# Date Picker using Jquery in iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, webview, datepicker

I want to load date picker using mobilscroll jQuery in iphone. So i have dropped those files of mobiscroll in xcode.and i have called index.html in webview.but in Webview i am not getting anything.
Nothing is displaying.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get empty screen. You should check all of the below items:

1. Remove js,html and css files from the Compile Sources and add them to the Copy Bundle Resources
2. You should be careful about the location of the JS and CSS files in the HTML files. Such as, when i develop UIWebView apps, I just copy the all of the js and css files to the documents directory in the AppDelegate file.

   ```
   NSString *jsFile2 = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"jquery-1.8.2.min.js"];
   NSString *jsFile2Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"jquery-1.8.2.min" ofType:@"js"];
   [fileManager copyItemAtPath:jsFile2Path toPath:jsFile2 error:nil];
   ```

Then, you can directly add css and js files to your html like that;
        `<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.min.js'></script>`

These are my concerns when I develop apps using UIWebView...